# How to do a `getOrElseComplete` on `Promise`?

Tags: scala, concurrency, promise, future

Does it make sense to have an operation like `getOrElseComplete` that tries to complete a `Promise` with a value but, if the `Promise` is already completed, returns the existing completed value instead. Here's a sample implementation:

```scala
implicit class PromiseOps[T](promise: Promise[T]) {
  def getOrElseComplete(value: Try[T]): Try[T] = {
    val didComplete = promise.tryComplete(value)
    if (didComplete) {
      value
    } else {
      // The `tryComplete` returned `false`, which means the promise
      // was already completed, so the following is safe (?)
      promise.future.value.get
    }
  }
}
```

Is this safe to do? If not, why not? If so, is there a way to do this directly (eg. without relying on questionable things like `_.value.get`) or why isn't there such a way in the standard library?

Comment: Why do you need this? It feels like the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @ghik I want to make a single atomic decision and there are multiple different threads that can make that decision (differently) depending on what is happening in the system. Then, I also want to be able to watch that decision for completion. I guess I could do this with an `AtomicReference` and a `Promise`, but given that a `Promise` is already wrapping an `AtomicReference` (to be thread-safe), it seems simpler to do this all with one promise object (less external invariants and less code).

Comment: There's no reason to use `Promise` if you're not giving its `Future` to someone. Your code doesn't show how you expose that `Future` so it's hard to say what would be the correct way to do this. This particular solution feels weird because `Promise` is supposed to be only a settable "backend" of a `Future` and you shouldn't use the `Promise` itself as a source of the result value.

Comment: I am giving its `Future` to someone. That's how the "watch that decision for completion" part is done. I want to both watch for completion and sometimes immediately locally know what that decision was.

Answer (score 2):

From your comments it seems to me that this is a valid solution for your problem but I also feel that a method like this doesn't belong in `Promise` API because `Promise` is supposed to be only a settable "backend" of its `Future`.

I'd prefer to have a completely separate function which could look like this:

```scala
def getOrComplete[T](promise: Promise[T], value: Try[T]): Try[T] =
  promise.future.value.getOrElse {
    if (promise.tryComplete(value)) value
    else getOrComplete(promise, value)
  }
```

The recursive call may seem weird - it serves two purposes:

- it protects against a race condition where some other thread completes the future *just* before we call `tryComplete`
- it avoids usage of `.value.get` on the `Future`

You might also want to pass `value` as a by-name parameter to avoid evaluating it when the `Promise` is already completed.

Comment: Very creative way to get rid of the ‘get’! I wonder how performance ends up given that even on the happy path you end up making two calls.

Comment: If you _really_ want to get rid of the second call then use pattern matching instead of `getOrElse` and the call becomes tail recursive which means that it's effectively eliminated in the bytecode.

Comment: Yeah, that would be better indeed - thanks for pointing out that call can be tail recursive.

Comment: @Alec, a Future from a Promise is the same object with a different interface, so calling `future` is free. I don't remember off hand how it's protected, but probably with a cheap uncontested read (I'd imagine it's read, if Some(x) return, else aquire lock, read, return)

Answer (score 1):

This operation does what it promises. It may make more sense to take `value` by name, and don't try to complete if already completed, maybe something like

```
def getOrElseComplete(value: => Try[T]): Try[T] = {
  if (!promise.completed) {
    promise.tryComplete(value)
  }
  promise.future.value.get
}
```

It's kinda dodgy though. Sharing a promise and having multiple places where it might be completed sounds like a difficult to maintain design, and one has to ask what's happening with the other path that might still complete the Promise? Shouldn't something be cancelled there?

Comment: The promise represents a decision outcome and there can be multiple concurrent codepaths that are racing to complete the `Promise`. The codepaths can do things like `tryComplete` and use the outcome of that to atomically try to make the "decision" all while checking if some other thread got there first. Elsewhere, I can watch the promise's `Future` and schedule some work for once the decision has been made.

Comment: Passing `value` by name does mean that sometimes `value` may get evaluated even if it doesn't end up being the promise completion value (eg. when racing two calls to `getOrElseComplete`). That's not a problem per se, but worth being aware of.